# How to evaluate Secure Authorization for server to client

Tags: design, authentication, oauth2

I have a customer that wants me to build a web portal (Asp.net 4.0) that will communicate with a desktop client, tablet and/or smart phone (e.g. iOS and/or Android).

I was thinking of using oAuth 2.0. But I'm not familiar with any potential cons to using OAuth. And I don't know how to compare OAuth to other Secure Authorization method/protocols that would be appropriate for this situation.

How should I evaluate OAuth to see if it's right for my project or if I should use a different protocol?

Comment: I dont like 'whats best' questions, but I think this question would be ok if it was tweaked to be more about pro/cons of oauth2.

Comment: for the record, this question is being discussed at [Whiteboard chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10885689#10885689) _'Looks too "Evaluate the options for me without any requirements"... etc'_